# Understanding Template Reference variable used in directives

Tags: angular

I am trying to create my own directive. Below is the code

```
  @Input() set appUnless(condition: boolean) {
if (!condition) {
  this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
 
} else {
  this.vcRef.clear();
}
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
```

This is where I have used the directive

```
<div *appUnless="onlyOdd">
      <li
      *ngFor="let even of evenNumbers"
      (click)="show($event)"
        class="list-group-item"
        [ngClass]="{odd: even % 2 !== 0}"
        [value]="even" 
        [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: even % 2 !== 0 ? 'yellow' : 'transparent'}"
        >
        {{ even }}
      </li>
    </div>
```

The doubt is what does **this.templateRef** returns. The template of the filed where the directive used or the directive itself
Can someone explain the code

Answer (score 0):

the thing is this magic star `*` syntax. during angular compilation of the template code

```
<div *ngIf="cond; else otherTpl">contentcontent</div>
```

is being transformed to

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="cond" [ngIfElse]="otherTpl"> // note, that else property is prefixed with ngIf - the before star piece of text
  <div>contentcontent</div>
</ng-template>
```

and here we can see that ngIf directive is used on ng-template element, and can inject it wia `constructor(ref: TemplateRef){}`